# Find and spilit numbers from a string PHP

Tags: php

I have textarea, string :

```
    __A 59.202x5p.
    __B 611.08 500p
    __C 991,70p.66.113.552.77.88.10p 199x200p
    __C2 33 44x100p 55 161x150p 25 33 85x60p 727 77 373 22x220p  
    __C3 44 16 59x10p 343 x15p 172 200p
```

i want output like this :

```
    __A 59.20 02x5p.
    __B 61 11.08 500p
    __C 99 91,70p.66.11 13.55 52.77.88.10p 19 99x200p
    __C2 33 22 44x100p 55 16 61 x150p 25 33 85x60p 72 27 77 37 73 22x220p  
    __C3 44 16 59x10p 34 43 x15p 17 72 200p
```

---

If number is hundreds and before "x ? p" or " ?p" ( ? is random number and cant spilit ), it will spilit and line will like this :

```
    __A 59.202x5p. >>>  __A 59.20 02x5p. 
    __B 611.08 500p >>>  __B 61 11.08 500p 
    __C 991,70p.66.113.552.77.88.10p 199x200p >>>  __C 99 91,70p.66.11 13.55 52.77.88.10p 19 99x200p
    ...
```

I use preg_match + preg_replace + substr but i cant locate where is hundreds number before "x ? p" or " ?p" ( ? is random number and cant spilit )...

And i dont understand how to spilit number like :

```
    __A 59."202"x5p. ( 202 to 20 02 ) >>>   __A 59.20 02x5p.
    __B 611.08 500p  ( 611 to 61 11 ) >>>  __B 61 11.08 500p
```

My English language not good, hope who read my question can understand and help me solve it.

Thank very very much.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code..

```
<?php
echo "<u>CURRENT STRING</u><br/>";
echo $value ="__A 59.202x5p.
         __B 611.08 500p
         __C 991,70p.66.113.552.77.88.10p 199x200p
         __C2 33 44x100p 55 161x150p 25 33 85x60p 727 77 373 22x220p  
         __C3 44 16 59x10p 343 x15p 172 200p";echo '<br>';

for($i=0;$i<=(strlen($value)-4); $i++ ) { 
    $myvar = $value[$i].$value[$i+1].$value[$i+2];      
    if (preg_match("/\d{3}/u", $myvar) > 0 && $myvar>100 && strpos($myvar.$value[$i+3], 'p') == 0)
    $value = substr($value,0,$i+2).' '.$value[$i+1].substr($value,$i+2,strlen($value));      
}
echo "<u>DESIRED STRING</u><br/>";
echo $value;
?>
```

Comment: It work very good, thank you very much... but i see, if number like : 010, 020... 0 is start ... number didnt spilit @___@
Hope you fix it.